# QTextBlock 効果が実感できないメソッド達について

Tags: python, python3, qt

`QTextBlock`を利用して、割注や縦中横の実現を企んでいます。
以前より疑問に思っていて、スッキリ！できなかったのですが、
①setLineCount,②setRevision,③setVisibleの３つについて
お尋ねしたいです。
　この３つは、読んで字のごとく、
①そのブロックの行の数をセットするもの。（ただし、全てのドキュメントレイアウトが
　この特徴を備えているわけではないと、リファレンスに注意書き。）
②そのブロックをリビジョン（改訂？）する。
③そのブロックを可視化する。
　というものだと考えているのですが、どれもいまいち効果がわかりません。
まず、setLineCount(2)として、ラインをセットしたとすると、
blockのlayoutを取得して、lineAt(1000)などとしても、エラーもなく
アドレスが帰ってきますし、lineはだからといって２行になっている
わけでもありません。素直に、２行になりゃいいのにと思うのに、なって
くれないのです。
　セットした以上のライン数を指定し、QTextLineを取得することができて
しまうのも、わけがわかりません。余分な指定は無視されて、全部現在の最
大数番目のlineが、帰って来るのか？（２とセットすれば、１０００だろうが
１００００だろうが、２のラインが帰って来る）と思ったのですが、判定は
Falseです。
　Revisionというのは、改訂という話なのでしょうが、何がどう改訂される
のかわけがわかりません。
　最後に、Visibleをセットして可視化しようと思っても、ブロックが可視化
されるわけではないので、非常にがっかりした経験があります。ブロックは
複雑なうえに、全くといっていいほど目に見えないからです。
　QTextLayout,QTextLine,QTextBlockの、3者の関係性については、理解
出来る部分もあるのですが、この特に①の特徴によって、長らく混乱させられ
てきました。
　何とか自分で解決しようと今までやってきたつもりなのですが、ついぞ、その
効果は理解できませんでした。
　どなたか、スッキリ！させていただけるような解答をお持ちではありませんか？
どうかお願いいたします。

Comment: `QTextEdit`を起動し、`tc.block()`,`block.layout()`と情報を取得します。そして、適当な文字を打ちまくって、２行３行とがらくた文章を作ります。そして、`block.lineCount()`とすると、確かに数は増えていきます。しかし、だからと言って、`setLineCount()`を行ったからと言って、当然のように２行３行へとなるわけではないようです。また、for i in range(200)として、`lineAt(i)`を出力すると、最低３つのQTextLineオブジェクトが帰ってきます。さらにそれに合わせて、`lineAt(i).rect()`を出力すると、Cにありがちな異常な座標が帰ってきます。これはいったいどういう事だろうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QTextBlock#setLineCount`, `QTextBlock#setRevision`, `QTextBlock#setVisible`は、ライブラリ実装を見る限り、内部処理(Layoutの描画等)でしか利用されていない模様です。
つまり、独自実装する際に、これらのプロパティを見て処理を振り分けられる、という程度の活用になるかと思います。(自動的は作用は期待しない)

＃Undo, Redo関係の機構は「Undo Framework」として別に存在します。

Comment: ありがとうございます。今後わけのわからないメソッドがあれば、内部処理なのだろうと疑ってみます。LineのRectは、行それ自体を指していたのではなく、おかげさまで、Lineを構成する最低4本の線の座標が返っていたのだろうと推測できます。つまり、ラインそれ自体のRectではなく、一本一本の線それ自体のRectですね。（何個返って来たかは忘れましたけど。）そして、lineAt(i)シーケンスでは、同じラインのアドレスがたくさん帰って来たので、きっと、上限というものは定められておらず、現在存在するラインが返ってくるようになっているのでしょう。異常な座標も、C++の内部処理と考えればわかります。確実に正解かどうかはわかりませんが、こう考えると得心です。Revisionも、Visibleも、何もしなければ、Blockに何の変更も加わらなくなったり、何も変化が感じられなくなるという無意味メソッドなのだろうと思います。（foregroundやbackgroundが設定されてないように見えるなど。）スッキリ！